# Can't only get large title with tableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

hey guys hope everyone is fine and safe

I'm actually implementing a table view for a new app and I want the title to always stay large, I don't want it to collapse when the user scrolls down and I'm fighting since this morning with my code, and nothing work. The last SO solutions I found about it were like from 3 years ago and don't work.

So I got a navigation controller and then my root view controller and then this table view controller

Here are the different presets used in storyboard

[nav bar storyboard presets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIpPU.png)

[root vc nav bar storyboard presets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJrOJ.png)

and there's the code of the table view controller

```
class PositionVC: UITableViewController {

let positions = ["QB", "WR", "RB", "TE", "OL", "DT", "DE", "EDGE", "LB", "CB", "S"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    title = "Positions"
    
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
    
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = .primaryBlue
    
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return positions.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = positions[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AlfaSlabOne-Regular", size: 25)

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.backgroundColor = .primaryBlue
}
```

tell me if you need to see anything else

thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on a project which also required large title not to collapse to a small one and it took me pretty long time to know that there is no other way to do so rather than hiding navigationController and setting UILabel with large font you need on a place of NavigationControllers title.

Here is the settings for UILabel I used in that process:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.clear
navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

let lbl: UILabel = {

```
      let label = UILabel()
      label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
      label.textColor = UIColor.black
      label.textAlignment = .left
      label.text = "Running Map"
      label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 35.0)
      
      return label
      
  }()
```

In order to place it right don't forget to use constraints

```
lbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        lbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        lbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        lbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 33).isActive = true
        lbl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -(view.frame.height * 0.844)).isActive = true
```